# How to make this lighting in Blender Internal?

Tags: node-editor, blender-internal-render-engine, light

Is there a way to emulate this node in *Internal*, and with diffuse textures on the model?

[image: Cycles - fx Node setup]

Take this low-poly sphere with a diffuse texture on it, for example. The first screenshot is the model rendered in Internal and the second is the model rendered in Cycles, with the effect on. (IOR: 3.000)

[image: Internal - LOD Sphere w/o fx]
[image: Cycles - LOD Sphere w/ fx]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean like this?  I guess I don't understand the question exactly because Blender Internal *does* have Fresnel:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU! I had no idea about this being possible in Internal so easily - I took your setup and altered it a bit and this alternate setup accomplishes just about exactly what I wanted! : https://i.imgur.com/K4waQAv.png . Two questions remain though - Is there a way to make the Fresnel lighting around the model stronger? Like, brighter I think is the correct word? (Here's comparisons : https://i.imgur.com/ihr1D8y.png ) Second question - the black area on the bottom mesh is *supposed* to be transparent. How can I make it so?

Comment: for the transparency, have you tried just connecting the Alpha output of the Material to the Alpha input on the Output node?  (assuming the image has an alpha channel)

Comment: I've attempted that out and it doesn't make a difference: https://imgur.com/a/ysSMSEd

Comment: for the 'brightness' you can insert a "Gamma" node between the Color output of the Material and the Color input of the Mix node, and then tweak the value up and down to make it brighter or dimmer https://imgur.com/a/Emfm3P6

Comment: for the alpha - your easiest bet would be to make that part of the image transparent in an image editor, and then use the alpha component. Otherwise it'd be hard to get ONLY that part transparent since it seems like other parts of the texture have black in them...so you can't assume black = transparent

Comment: also: if you feel like I answered your question, please 'accept' it as the correct answer. thanks!